# Folium. Map. GeoJson. Как обвести свою область? Как ограничить размер карты?

Tags: python, geojson

[image: map]Разбираюсь с примером по построению карты.

```
fgv = folium.FeatureGroup(name="polygon")
fgv.add_child(folium.GeoJson(data=open('world.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig').read()
```

Данные строчки создают слой, который выделяет границы стран и заливает сами страны синим цветом. Мне хотелось бы понять по какому принципу определяются эти границы и как правильно выбирать для них координаты, чтобы обвести свою область.

Так же интересует как я могу ограничить размер карты? По умолчанию можно листать карту влево и вправо до бесконечности, т.е, чтобы была только основная карта, выделенная цветами на скриншоте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На вопрос с картой ответа не нашел: как ограничить ее размер(не зум)

Однако разобрался, каким образом задавать координаты в json файл, чтобы обвести свою область, возможно кому-то поможет это:

```
{ "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
      { "type": "Feature",
         "geometry": {
           "type": "Polygon",
           "coordinates": [
             [ [долгота, широта], [долгота, широта], [долгота, широта],
               [долгота, широта], [долгота, широта] ]
             ]
         },
         "properties": {
           "prop0": "value0",
           "prop1": {"this": "that"}
           }
         }
       ]
     }
```

Таким образом формируется json файл, после чего:

```
fgv = folium.FeatureGroup(name="Polygon")
fgv.add_child(folium.GeoJson(data=open('world.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig').read()))
```

Этот код обведет область в виде многоугольника. Небольшое примечание, в гугле координаты идут вида широта, долгота, тут же надо указывать наоборот — долгота, широта
Изначально цвет контура и заливки синий, дабы его изменить:

```
fgv = folium.FeatureGroup(name="Polygon")
fgv.add_child(folium.GeoJson(data=open('world.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig').read(), style_function=lambda x:{'fillColor': 'red', 'color': 'red'}))
```